Next 14 Server Component data fetching causes error
my project
// src/pages/index.js
Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
    return <MainLayout>{page}</MainLayout>;
};

// MainLayout 
const MainLayout: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Header
      />

      {children}

      <Footer />
      <CookieWarning />
    </>
  );
};

export default MainLayout;

// page
<><MainPage/></>

// MainPage
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:9000/api/cart/qty")
  return await response.json()
}

export default async function MainPage() {
  const data = await getData()
  return (
    <div className={cn('main-page')}>
      <div className={cn('title-section')}>
        <div className={cn('title')}>
          <p>
            some text
          </p>
          {/*{qty.qty}*/}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

Causes error
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

you are mixin next 12 and 13 features... src/pages/index.js should be src/app/page.tsx for you to have access to that syntax.
